# Get page->parent's name?

Tags: post-meta

How can i get the name of a page's parent?
I can only get it's id.

```
        $page = get_queried_object();
        $pageparent = $page->post_parent;
```

Comment: Can you be clearer please ... a post is related to a category or tag     posts are not linked to pages (pages are static and usually dont have categories or tags)

Comment: @damien, it's a page, hierarchical one. i've edited the question, thanks

Comment: ok ill edit the question ... but have you checked the related results -----> or read up on get_pages http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page

Comment: i just tried with get_page, even then i can only get direct parent's and all ancestors 'id'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the id of a post or page, use `get_the_title($id)` to get the page title (which is what I assume you mean by name)

[Codex Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)

Comment: Thank you, never though there's such a function.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `get_queried_object` will only work on pages with a single post (or page) on them.  For example, if you were trying to find a parent of a post on a category archive page, `get_queried_object` would return the category, not the current post.

So, using the following would work in more circumstances:

```
global $post;
$parent_title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb;
$page_id = YOUR_PAGE_ID; //your page id here.
$parent_page_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
    SELECT post_parent 
    FROM $wpdb->posts 
    WHERE ID=$page_id;
    " 
) );
$parent_page_title = get_the_title($parent_page_id);
echo $parent_page_title; //this will print parent page title.
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title